# Xpath. How to get the node following text()

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

[image: Text]

This is the structure I try to parse.
I have a for loop for every child in p. I need to get the Name and associated number in `<sup>` node.
desired output would be like:
*Toloo, 1;
William C Baker, 2;
etc.*
here is my for loop:

```
for b in i.xpath('./p/text() | ./p/b/text()'):
    b.xpath('.//following-sibling::sup[1]/text()').get()
```

It does not return any result. Where am I wrong?
PS. If u run xpath without for loop it gets the thing done:

```
i.xpath('./p[2]/text()/following-sibling::sup/text() | ./p[2]/b/text()/following-sibling::sup/text()').getall()
['2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2']
```

Comment: Providing the input as TEXT, and not as IMAGE might help others help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your posts, guys.
What I did was actually parsing all the text nodes and then for each of them finding first preceding-sibling. That appeared to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details:
link, parser (html, lmxl...), scraper (beautifoulsoup, selenium...), the desired output format (list, dict...), do you really need ";" as separator?

If the number of names **ALWAYS** matches the number of numbers then try this:

So given your image:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

f = StringIO('<p><b>Toloo Taghian</b><sup>1</sup>", Willam C. Baker"<sup>1</sup>", Stephanie Bertrand"<sup>2</sup></p>')
i = etree.parse(f)
```

Then:

```
groups = i.xpath('//p')

for el in groups:
  name = el.xpath('.//text()')
```

Result:

```
['Toloo Taghian', '1', '", Willam C. Baker"', '1', '", Stephanie Bertrand"', '2']
```

Then:

```
name2 = list(zip(name[::2], name[1::2]))
```

Result as a list of tuples:

```
[('Toloo Taghian', '1'),
 ('", Willam C. Baker"', '1'),
 ('", Stephanie Bertrand"', '2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider list comprehension e.g. `result = [text.xpath('concat(., ": ", following-sibling::sup[1])') for text in i.xpath('./p/text() | ./p/b/text()')]`